# How to use --headless-rendering on Fortress

Tags: ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I ran this line, `ign gazebo -r models/sdf/freenove_smart_car.sdf --headless-rendering` and `ign gazebo --headless-rendering -r models/sdf/freenove_smart_car.sdf`

Both return the same result where it display GUI and made an output like this:

```
ign gazebo Unable to setup EGL (headless mode)
```

[image: image description]

Is this expected or a bug?

If this is the bug, I will close this and create an issue on the github.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27492/how-to-use---headless-rendering-on-fortress/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This was bug. It's fixed now. If you want to learn how to use it, use `ign gazebo --help` in command line

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2022-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0